How to create Marklogic TDE view from optic query
According to the MarkLogic documentation here, it's possible to create a TDE view from an Optic query. The documentation mentions that after running the op:generate-view query and inserting the resulting XML into the schema database, the view should be created.
I have followed this process, retrieved the XML results, and inserted them into the schema database, but the index does not seem to be triggered to generate the view.
Could you provide any guidance on what might be missing or if there are any additional steps or configurations needed to successfully generate the view from the Optic query?

You are likely missing a required collection: http://marklogic.com/xdmp/qbv
Please see the example further down on this page: Query Based Views

Thanks @David. It works after tagging the collection. However, it is not indexing the view, it is most like wrapping logic in a function and calling it !!!! is there any way to index this query  view and make it like the TDE templates?

Query-based views do not get indexed. They are intended to provide simple queries to run, but are not performance boosters.

Thanks, @DaveCassel I was looking to this approach for boosting the performance. Now I search for another approach to achieve that.

QBV may still be part of your solution. But they are best suited to join together views(or ins some cases starting differently). You still need to be careful of hungry joins and the use of op:bind and xpath etc (runtime operations) on un-paginated plans.

If you're using ml-gradle, you can do this via the instructions at https://github.com/marklogic/ml-gradle/wiki/Loading-schemas#generating-query-based-views .
